# Can an iOS user play with pc users?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I have a Mac only, so I am not able to get Terraria through Steam. I was wondering if I can play Terraria on my iPad Mini with a friend who has it on his PC. I was wondering this, because I saw that Deepworld on iOS is compatible with the Mac version.

Comment: One thing to consider is that almost all fairly modern Macs can dual-boot OS X and Windows very well through Boot Camp.

Comment: Yes, I am considering using that. I just have to find a copy of Windows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The mobile and PC versions of Terraria have different content and are **not compatible** with each other. This *might* change in the future, but it seems unlikely at the time.

Comment: I really don't understand why developpers use *different content*. It's just more work and less fun!

Comment: @TomášZato because the different versions may have different development cycles/schedules or in some cases different versions are contracted out and therefore not even made by the same programmers. Also sometime target OSs may have different libraries available thus limiting what can be included in different versions. Mobile devices have a whole different interface requiring differing approaches to similar problems (such as PC mob ai may not be 'fair' on  mobile given a greater difficulty maneuvering. These are just related to Terraria and Minecraft.

Comment: @ydobonebi This just points to poor management and insufficient level of software abstraction.

Answer (score -1):

As for you mac,

I have three friends with macs, and over 50 friends with pc's who play Terraria. However, my three friends and I still manage to get together and play Terraria on my PC server using V-mare fusion. Using it, they launch windows on their mac, run steam on it, and then run terraria on steam. Its a great solution and as far I'm concerned it should work for you.

The best part is, that V-Mare might take some time to boot, but once its up you can slide between windows and your mac. Its simple!

Comment: He's not using a Mac, he's using an Ipad Mini.
So he's not using Mac OSX, but iOS. So you don't answer his question.

Comment: @SirKsilem BUT hes using the IpadMini, beause he cant solve the problem on the Mac. Please understand the problem before making a rash move like voting down.

Comment: His question is if iOS can play with PC. Why he does it is something to discuss is the comments.